# Chart.js changes selected legend filters when using update function

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using Chart.js to display a stacked bar chart on my webpage. I'm trying to make this chart automatically update on the page without user intervention, to do that, I'm using AJAX.

```
setInterval(function() {

    $.get("ajax?type=chart_update&id={{ @GET.id }}", function(data){
        myChart.data = JSON.parse(data);
        myChart.update(0);
    });

}, 60000);
```

This successfully resets the chart every 60 seconds.

However, a problem arises when a user has filtered out a certain data set by clicking it in the legend. When the `update()` function is ran, this filter is also reset. It seems to me that this shouldn't be expected behavior, I'm not trying to update the view of the table but only the data to keep it current.

How can I make this filter not get reset when the data in the table is updated?

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/GrumpyCrouton/pen/mdbgVKM) to show this issue. To recreate it, simply click on one of the values in the legend then click the "Update Table" button to show that the legend gets reset every time.

Comment: You're right, this isn't expected behaviour. `update()` should only update the data. Can you post your code?

Comment: @HeadhunterKev I added a codepen example.

Comment: Thanks for the pen, for me it's very important. I've posted an answer down below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a fan of combined charts and data. I want `data` and `options` as separate variables. Then your `update()` works as a charm and is much shorter and easier to read. 
[JSBin with all the code](https://jsbin.com/payetukabe/2/edit?html,js,output)

```
var chartOptions = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            stacked: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
            stacked: true
        }]
    }
}

var chartData = {
    labels: ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'First',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5],
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    },{
        label: 'Second',
        data: [5, 19, 3, 5],
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
    },{
        label: 'Third',
        data: [8, 19, 3, 5],
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    },{
        label: 'Fourth',
        data: [9, 19, 3, 5],
        backgroundColor: 'orange'
    }]
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var stackedBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartData,
    options: chartOptions
});

function updateChart() {
    chartData.datasets.forEach(function(element) {
        element.data = r();
    });
    stackedBar.update();
}

function r() {
    var values = [];
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
        values.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    }
    return values;
}
```

Comment: So you only have to update the original variable you used to initialize the chart, and not the `stackedBar.data` variable? I'm not really understanding how that updates the table

Comment: Basically. You update your data in the variable and your chart uses the updated data. I never did it the way you posted and many other people use it. But I don't know of any disadvantages my way. Your question is a perfect example for that.

Comment: Should it work if I replace the whole `chartData` variable? The labels may change... I've currently switched to this in my actual project and it doesn't seem to update at all

Comment: It shouldn't change much in your code. This way you are sure that you only change the data and not the whole chart. It should work fine. If you want to change the labels, you can update them the same way. `chartData.labels = ['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th']; stackedBar.update();`

Comment: Okay, I've got this working. Do you think you could take a look at my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105362/chart-js-not-resorting-rows-based-on-plugin-after-using-update-function) regarding chartjs?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Seems like you removed your other question. Don't you need an answer anymore or did you manage it on your own? It took me quite some time to fix that and it's quite complexe so I would be happy to see your solution to that!

Comment: I actually ended up just doing it server side, however, I would be happy to undelete my question so you can post an answer, might help others. EDIT: Undeleted