# Chart.js not resorting rows based on plugin after using update function

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm displaying a stacked bar chart on my page. When I initialize the table, I sort the data so that it is displayed in descending order by total in each dataset.

To do this, I'm using a custom plugin

```
Chart.plugins.register({                                                                                                                                                             
    datasets: [],                                                                                                                                                                    
    getData(labels, datasets) {                                                                                                                                                      
        const sum = [];                                                                                                                                                              
        for (i = 0; i < datasets[0].length; i++) {                                                                                                                                   
            sum.push({                                                                                                                                                               
                label: labels[i],                                                                                                                                                    
                data: datasets.map(e => e[i]),                                                                                                                                       
                    get sum() { // ES6 - getter                                                                                                                                      
                        return this.data.reduce((a, b) => a + b);                                                                                                                    
                    }                                                                                                                                                                
            });                                                                                                                                                                      
        }                                                                                                                                                                            
        return sum;                                                                                                                                                                  
    },                                                                                                                                                                               
    beforeInit(chart) {                                                                                                                                                              
        chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, datasetIndex) => {                                                                                                                     
            this.datasets.push(dataset.data);                                                                                                                                        
        });                                                                                                                                                                          
        const data_store = this.getData(chart.data.labels, this.datasets).sort((a,b) => b.sum - a.sum);                                                                              

        data_store.forEach((d,i) => {                                                                                                                                                
            chart.data.labels[i] = d.label;                                                                                                                                          
            d.data.forEach((v, vi) => {                                                                                                                                              
                chart.data.datasets[vi].data[i] = v;                                                                                                                                 
            });                                                                                                                                                                      
        });                                                                                                                                                                          
    }                                                                                                                                                                                
});
```

Now, every 60 seconds I am running some AJAX to grab updated data to refresh the chart.

```
setInterval(function() {

    $.get("ajax?type=chart_update&id={{ @GET.id }}", function(data){
        var data = JSON.parse(data);

        data.datasets.forEach(function(value, key) {
            chart_data.datasets[key].data = value.data;
        });
        chart_data.labels = data.labels;

        myChart.update();
    });

}, 60000);
```

However, when I run the update function, the data is no longer sorted. I've tried to use different hooks in my plugin instead of `beforeInit` such as `beforeUpdate`, `beforeRender`, and `beforeDraw`, but these either made no difference, makes the chart render weirdly, or I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

How can I sort the data again after updating?

Comment: I don't think you need a plugin for that. Just pass the sorted data to your chart. Can you quickly explain how the data should be sorted? That's easier than looking though your code.

Comment: @HeadhunterKev Each bar has 4 sets of data, and I want to sort them in descending order from highest total to lowest. These values are computed server side. The X axis ends up being the name of the person who entered the data, and each bar represents different values. I didn't want to do this server side, as it seemed easier to do it client side, and it worked until I needed to make the chart reload occasionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sorting is quite complexe because you can't simply change the data, you need to know the order for the labels as well. You find my code in the [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/cabexutala/2/edit?js,output). I hope this is what you want.

Complete code:

```
let chartOptions = {
  scales: {
    xAxes: [{
      stacked: true
    }],
    yAxes: [{
      stacked: true
    }]
  }
}

let chartData = {
  labels: ["FirstValue", "SecondValue", "ThirdValue", "FourthValue"],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'FirstDataset',
    data: [12, 55, 33, 85],
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },{
    label: 'SecondDataset',
    data: [95, 15, 73, 5],
    backgroundColor: 'blue'
  },{
    label: 'ThirdDataset',
    data: [38, 17, 73, 45],
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  },{
    label: 'FourthDataset',
    data: [49, 89, 33, 85],
    backgroundColor: 'orange'
  }]
}

let sortedData = sortData(chartData)

let ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
let stackedBar = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: sortedData,
  options: chartOptions
});

function sortData(chartData) {
  console.log('#############')
  console.log('beforeSort', chartData)
  let arraySum = []
  let sortedData = {}
  sortedData.labels = []
  sortedData.datasets = []

  // Calculate the total sum of all datasets for each label
  for (let i = 0; i < chartData.labels.length; i++) {
    let dataSum = 0
    chartData.datasets.map(obj => {
      dataSum += obj.data[i]
    })
    arraySum.push(dataSum)
  }
  //console.log("Data sum", arraySum)

  // Get a lookup-table with the order of the labels
  let arrayLookupTable = []
  for (let i = 0; i < chartData.labels.length; i++) {
    let index = arraySum.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null,arraySum))
    arrayLookupTable.push(index)
    arraySum[index] = -1
  }
  //console.log("arrayLookupTable", arrayLookupTable)

  // Assign the sorted labels
  for (let i = 0; i < chartData.labels.length; i++) {    
    sortedData.labels.push(chartData.labels[arrayLookupTable[i]])
  }

  // Assign the sorted datasets
  for (let i = 0; i < chartData.datasets.length; i++) {
    sortedData.datasets.push(chartData.datasets[i])
    //previous line copies complete dataset with old data which gets sorted in the next line
    sortedData.datasets[i].data = changeDataOrder(sortedData.datasets[i].data, arrayLookupTable)
  }

  console.log("afterSort", sortedData)
  return sortedData
}

function changeDataOrder(previousDataArray, arrayLookupTable) {
  //console.log('changeDataOrder', previousDataArray, arrayLookupTable)
  let newDataArray = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayLookupTable.length; i++) {
    newDataArray.push(previousDataArray[arrayLookupTable[i]])
  }
  return newDataArray
}

function updateChart() {
  chartData.datasets.forEach(function(element) {
    element.data = r(chartData.labels.length);
  });

  let updatedChart = sortData(chartData)
  stackedBar.config.data.labels = updatedChart.labels; //labels have to be updated separately
  stackedBar.update();
}

function r(length) {
  let values = [];
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
    values.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
  }
  return values;
}
```